# Error in installing gem libxml-ruby version 2.4.0 on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have ruby 2.4.0 . I need to install libxml-ruby with same version. I did install the default libxml-ruby but still while running ruby script I am getting below error:
``` C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in ``require': cannot load such file -- libxml_ruby (LoadError) ```

Ruby version:
ruby 2.4.10p364 (2020-03-31 revision 67879) [x64-mingw32]

Below is the gem list :
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.2)
bundler (2.2.7)
cmath (1.0.0)
deep_merge (1.2.1)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
happymapper (0.5.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (2.5.1, default: 2.0.4)
libxml-ruby (2.9.0 x64-mingw32)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0, 2.3.0)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.10.9 x64-mingw32, 1.8.4 x64-mingw32)
openssl (default: 2.0.9)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
racc (1.5.2)
rake (12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.1)
test-unit (3.2.3)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
zlib (1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing on your `gemfile` the line `gem 'libxml-ruby'` for `gem 'libxml-ruby', '< 3.1'` to limit gem version. I had this same problem and I solved it using a lower version than 3.1 of the gem.

Run `bundle` after this change and run rails again.